# Using schema.xml instead of managed schema with Solr 5.1.X

Tags: xml, solr

I am trying to use schema.xml with the latest version of Solr (5.1.0). It seems that by default Solr 5.1.0 uses managed schema, but I would like to use schema.xml for a specific collection.

So I create a new collection (using solr create -c my_collection on windows and copy schema.xml from

```
server\solr\configsets\basic_configs\conf\schema.xml
```

to

```
server\solr\my_collection\conf\schema.xml
```

After that I change settings in

```
server\solr\my_collection\conf\solrconfig.xml
```

to use

```
<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>
```

After doing this I get an exception when starting the server:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:    fieldType 'booleans' not found in the schema
```

Am I doing something terribly wrong here? Should not this kind of logic work?

UPDATE:
Stractrace looks like this:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: fieldType 'booleans' not found in the schema
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:885)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:652)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:518)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:283)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:277)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: fieldType 'booleans' not found in the schema
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory$TypeMapping.populateValueClasses(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:244)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.inform(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:170)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:620)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:868)
```

Comment: Can you check if your schema file has this line                                           <fieldType name="booleans" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" multiValued="true"/>

Comment: No, there seems to be no such fieldType.

Comment: Are you using SolrCloud? How did you start your servers? Can you check if any of your fields are using the fieldtype booleans? So for example, there might be a field in your schema <field name="randomfield" type="booleans"  indexed="true" stored="true"/>  , if thats the case, then you need to define that fieldType also in your schema

Comment: I am not using solr server. I start the server simply with "solr start" and create an empty collection (later actions are described in the post, it should be reproducible). There is no occurrence of "booleans" in schema.xml file.

Comment: Can you post the entire error stack trace?

Comment: Posted the stacktrace, but there seems to be a workaround that I found, will post it as an answer in a while.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that you are referencing a field type `booleans` that is not defined in your `schema.xml` file. When you create a core a file `managed-schema` is created in `server\solr\my_collection\conf\`. Rename this file to `schema.xml` and restart solr with `ClassicIndexSchemaFactory` and it will work fine.

Comment: Yes, this worked. Could you share where you came up with this idea? Or you simply figured out that managed schema and schema.xml have the same format?

Comment: Hi. I noticed that a file named `managed-schema` appeared in my `conf` directory and figured out that it's the same as `schema.xml` file. Thats just a way solr encountered to remove visibility of `schema` file in the Solr API when the `schemaless` mode is set.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but somehow that did not seem that intuitive for me (hadn't used earlier versions and had to migrate an older collection). I hope this helps other frustrated developers. Thanks.

Comment: I am fairly new to solr , can anyone tell how to start solr with ClassicIndexSchemaFactory?

Comment: Take care of comments , they have purpose there. In managed-schema, the comments says "This is the Solr schema file. This file should be named "schema.xml"...blah blah blah

Comment: @Nilesh add `<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>` to `solarconfig.xml` in the conf folder

Comment: Did anyone get string and full text fields indexed ? I have boolean and integer fields indexed but string and fulltext fields are not getting indexed. Any thoughts ?. Btw, I used sunspot's schema and solrconfig.xml files.

Answer (score 12):

The problem that I had here was had nothing to do with actually using the `booleans` field type. The problem was that the newly upgraded `solrconfig.xml` file has a processor for unknown fields enabled by default, which needs the `booleans` field type, and probably some others.

These are all defined by default in the new example `schema.xml`, but quite possibly not in your old `schema.xml`.

The solution for me was to comment out the `<updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema">` section in `solrconfig.xml`.

Alternatively, you can probably just replace `solrconfig.xml`.

Comment: My data was in xml file and consisted of 5 fields. I only wanted to process 3 fields. I defined those 3 fields in my schema.xml and followed your advice to comment out the section of updateRequestProcessorChain. I didn't work for me. 
Later I also mentioned the remaining two fields but changed the field properties to index=false, stored=false. Then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Field type {booleans} is not defined in `schema.xml`.

Steps to fix it,

- Remove collection
- Rename the `managed-schema` file to `schema.xml`
- Modify `solrconfig.xml` to replace the schemaFactory class.
- a) Remove any `ManagedIndexSchemaFactory` definition if it exists.
- b) Add a `ClassicIndexSchemaFactory` definition as shown below,

`<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>`

- Update `autoCreateFields` to false in `solrconfig.xml` or you will get

`This IndexSchema is not mutable` error.

`${update.autoCreateFields:false}`

- Recreate collection.